# Jar-Exe converted files execution

Tags: java, jar, jvm, exe

I've converted a jar application to an exe because I want to execute this app on computers which not have installed java.

But the .exe file (the old jar) still want JVM or will be executed by Windows?

Comment: Can you provide more information please?  How did you do the conversion?  What commands did you use?  What error specifically are you getting?

Comment: Note C++ programs typically need a runtime environment to run also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends entirely on whether the method you're using to convert your JAR to an EXE includes the Java runtime in (or alongside) the EXE. If it doesn't, it will have to locate the JRE on the computer it's executing on.

If you feel like elaborating a little, perhaps we can give a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thank you! I understand.

Answer (score 1):

The implication in the question is that the .jar file was simply renamed to have a .exe extension. If this is what was done, it will not work.

To package a .jar as a .exe that includes its own jvm, look at tools like:

https://www.duckware.com/jexepack/index.html

http://www.jar2exe.com/

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/